# How to remove HTML code in the body of the email when recieving email?

Tags: html, oracle, email, workflow

I have a user who is recieving automated email from Oracle Workflow system. But the email is displayed with HTML code in its body. This doesnt happen for any other user recieving similar emails nor does it happen for other emails that this user recieves.

See attached picture for more clarifications.

[image]

Comment: It looks like the Oracle Workflow system generated such an email. You may try to forward the email to any other addres and see how it looks. I am sure the HTML tags will be displayed on other PCs.

Comment: It's not just the HTML code that's being shown; it's the entire SMTP mail body (note the SMTP headers). Either the mail client is not reading it correctly, or the sender is mucking it up somehow.

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshot it looks a little like there are line breaks within the recipient address (To-Field). Therefore the following Header fields are accounted to the body, not the header of the mail. Try to change the name or address of the recipient in question.